# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' pigpiod

Tags: raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, gpio, python

So I create an another program that can run stepper motor clockwise and counter clockwise with a ramp up and ramp down in there and adding limiter switch on GPIO 16 and 26 to stop the `pi.wave_send_using_mode(wid2, pigpio.WAVE_MODE_ONE_SHOT_SYNC)` giving a chain wave, this is my code:

```
import time
import pigpio

START_DELAY=600
FINAL_DELAY=500
STEP=1

GPIO=20

pi = pigpio.pi()

pi.set_mode(GPIO, pigpio.OUTPUT)
pi.set_mode(21, pigpio.OUTPUT)
pi.set_mode(26,pigpio.INPUT)
pi.set_mode(16,pigpio.INPUT)
#pi.write(21,1)
pi.wave_clear()

statee = 0
try:
    while True:

        pi.write(21,statee)
        pi.wave_clear()

        wf=[]
        offset = pi.wave_get_micros()
        for delay in range(START_DELAY, FINAL_DELAY, -STEP):
           wf.append(pigpio.pulse(1<<GPIO, 0,       delay))
           wf.append(pigpio.pulse(0,       1<<GPIO, delay))

        for i in range(500):
            wf.append(pigpio.pulse(1<<GPIO, 0,       FINAL_DELAY))
            wf.append(pigpio.pulse(0,       1<<GPIO, FINAL_DELAY))
        wf.append(pigpio.pulse(0, 0, offset))

        for delay in range(FINAL_DELAY, START_DELAY, STEP):
           wf.append(pigpio.pulse(1<<GPIO, 0,       delay))
           wf.append(pigpio.pulse(0,       1<<GPIO, delay))

        pi.wave_add_generic(wf)

        wid2 = pi.wave_create()

        #pi.wave_send_once(wid2)
        pi.wave_send_using_mode(wid2, pigpio.WAVE_MODE_ONE_SHOT_SYNC)

        if pi.read(26) == 0:
            pi. wave_tx_stop()
            pi.stop()
        if pi.read(16) == 0:
            pi.wave_tx_stop()
            pi.stop()

        time.sleep(0.75)
        if statee == 0:
            statee = 1
        elif statee == 1:
            statee = 0
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("\nCtrl-C pressed.  Stopping PIGPIO and exiting...")
    pi.wave_tx_stop()
    pi.stop()
```

The problem happens when the motor runs around 5 - 10 minutes, it give an error message like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/home/pi/Desktop/ramp.py", line 49, in <module>
    if pi.read(16) == 0:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1401, in read
    return _u2i(_pigpio_command(self.sl, _PI_CMD_READ, gpio, 0))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 989, in _pigpio_command
    sl.s.send(struct.pack('IIII', cmd, p1, p2, 0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

So, what the cause of error in my code? Is that cause by `pi.read(26)` and `pi.read(16)`? Is there any other ways to stop or terminate `pi.wave_send_using_mode(wid2, pigpio.WAVE_MODE_ONE_SHOT_SYNC)` at the middle of it process? thank you
small note: I set pigpiod daemon start on boot by folow (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70568/how-to-run-pigpiod-on-boot   KimSJ answer), is the method of runimg pigpiod cause this error? thank you

Comment: It's hard to understand your process but the general bug seems like  an IO race condition.  define Chainwave characteristics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your problem is that you are calling pi.stop in the middle of your task.](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#stop)

"Stop" doesn't mean "stop the servo from moving."

It means "stop and close the connection to the pigpio service."

So, you call stop in the middle of your task and then try to send commands over the closed connection.  It has been closed and disposed of, so an attempt to access it returns an object of type "None" which (of course) doesn't have a "send" method.

Stop using "stop" except at the end when your program no longer needs the pigpio object.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the pigpio code, it appears that the socket is being closed. Are you sure the thread is still running? I would start looking into what the background thread is doing when the socket gets closed.